# What is the recommended way to handle one-time-password when using APIs for authentication?

Tags: laravel, api, session, tdd, one-time-password

I am using TDD to implement APIs for an authentication system in Laravel. This system uses the one-time-password (OTP) method for authentication. In the first step, an OTP token is issued for the user and stored in the `session`. In the second step, the server receives a request containing an OTP token from the user and checks if the received OTP token is identical to the one stored in the `session`.

I have written a test for a scenario where the user sends an invalid OTP token to the server, but I don't have access to the server `session` in the test, so I cannot compare the invalid token against the session value.

Is there a better way than using sessions to implement this? Is there a solution to access the server `session` in the test?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Database

Add a column to the users table for OTP

**Step 1:**

- generate OTP and issue to the customer
- Store OTP in database

**Step 2:**

- Server receives request from user with OTP
- compare against value in database and delete from database

Pros: Simple to setup

Cons: Additional database queries and need to remember to delete it even if after issuing OTP to user request from user is never made

#### Cache

**Step 1:**

- Generate and issue OTP to user
- Store OTP in Cache

```php
Cache::put("otp-{$user->id}", OTP, now()->addMinutes(5));
```

**Step 2:**

- Server receives request from user with
- Check against the value in cache

Pros: Simple to setup and OTP can be destroyed automatically

Cons: Cache management becomes vital area of application